# Performance Metrics on SO?

Tags: discussion, users, statistics, metrics

I've been noticing recently that everyone in the world has more points than me on SO, and I began to wonder: is my number of answers above or below the mean for my score range? Is my mean votes/answer consistent with my score range? And then the same with my questions...

These are some initial metrics which are probably not so good (even comparing to my score range might be wrong), but:

1. What metrics would be interesting for performance on SO (aside from pure score)?
2. Has a metrics feature been contemplated on Meta before (and would it be interesting)?

[I know the data dump is available and that is one way to analyze for myself.]

Comment: Please see the many questions tagged [statistics]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics

Comment: Thanks @Ether, now I know my Jon Skeet number too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I calculated the percentage of my answers which have been accepted: **39%** for me.

You can calculate it by searching `user:me isaccepted:0` and then `user:me isaccepted:1`

Comment: Wow, I am definitely lacking in accepted answers. Where is this pseudo-query language documented?

Comment: @Yar - Leave the search query field blank and hit `Enter`. Located here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate this is, though. I ran it and found 113 non-accepted and 195 accepted answers, which obviously isn't right because I have a little over 500 answers.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [GreaseMonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13847/display-statistics-have-subject-badges-for-accepted-answers) a while back that adds the percentage of answers accepted to your answers summary. The output looks like this:

[image: Accepted answers shot]

Comment: excellent. Where is the script, in that question?

Comment: @Yar yes currently it is, I've been meaning to add it to userscripts.org for a while but keep getting distracted by other shiny th