# Search doesn't return all answers

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, answers, search

Hmmm... either I'm stupid or something is wrong. I just tried [Koper's idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40805/performance-metrics-on-so/40806#40806) to find my ratio of accepted and not accepted answers on SO.

> user:me isaccepted:0

[returns 52 answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a115866%20isaccepted%3a0),

> user:me isaccepted:1

[returns 72](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a115866%20isaccepted%3a1). According to my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha), I have a total of 218 answers. What am I missing (besides 94 answers)? Just searching for

> user:me

on the other hand finds 232 results, although it should be 218+11=229.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because `isaccepted:0` returns the 52 answers you've given where the question has *no* accepted answer. Presumably there are another 94 questions where an answer has been accepted, but it was not one of yours.

Comment: Shouldn't that be the difference between `hasaccepted` and `isaccepted`?

Comment: @Arjan perhaps the semantics are jumbled, but `hasaccepted` means another thing. If I query `user:me hasaccepted:0`, that will return all the questions *I have asked* that are not accepted.

Comment: Oh of course, questions versus answers, `hasaccepted` and `isaccepted` are probably unrelated indeed.

Comment: this is correct

Comment: If Jeff says so I guess I can believe it. Accepted.

Comment: I don't think I believe it though. I'm never right

Comment: There's always a first time :)