# Badge Proposal: Problem Solver

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Badges For Accepted Answers More than X](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47095/badges-for-accepted-answers-more-than-x)

As a relatively new SE acolyte it seems odd to me that there is no badge directly tied to the amount of accepted answers. It seems logical that the goal of answering a question should be to provide one that the asker finds satisfactory. SE seems to already support that ideology by awarding more reputation for an accepted answer than a upvote, so I'm surprised that there are basically no badges directly tied to this.

It seems strange to me that a user could potentially piggy back on high volume questions providing supplementary answers and get a lot of votes but not contribute to satisfying the site's question base (not to say that supplementary questions are bad). I'm just saying that I think it makes sense to provide incentive to not only display knowledge and popular opinion but also to reward good listeners and problem solvers that are aiding in the site's overall purpose.

Comment: Wouldn't this just encourage users to delete their low-score unaccepted answers which may still be valuable?

Comment: That's a valid point against the percentage option; maybe it would be better as a numeric one (e.g. not 20% accepted but instead 500 accepted answers).

Comment: Ehh...there's already enough jockeying about acceptance. Also, badges tend to be for things that are good for the site, but _not_ rewarded by rep. Rep^H^H^HThe dopamine rush^W^W^WHelping others is its own reward.

Comment: The "duplicate" is different than this question.

Comment: Agree - I'm the author of the supposed duplicate, and it's not the same.

Comment: "different" as in clearer as to what it's rewarding?

Comment: Different because it is referring to a beefed up "Enlightened" badge that is the result of 1 accepted answer with _many_ votes. This question is referring to _many_ accepted answers.

Comment: Different as in different.  I was asking why there are two silver badges for accepted answers but no gold ones.  OP here is *requesting* a *new* badge to be rewarded for accepted answers being a certain % of all answers

Comment: Here you go then: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47095/badges-for-accepted-answers-more-than-x

Comment: Oddly, the word percentage killed this one for me - but the dup is a good idea I think.  *Goes to open a bounty*

Comment: I understand the desire to not reopen things and discuss them _ad nauseum_, but two years seems like a fair amount of time to pass to discuss something that didn't get much air time and seemed to have support.

Comment: This leads in users asking OPs to accept their answers which will be awkward

Comment: @Conner - there's a bounty on the linked dup - go there and make your case.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka - true.  That's the one possible negative to giving badges for X accepts.  Still though, most users have too much pride to go begging for checkmarks.  At least I hope so....

Comment: @AdamRackis I'm one of them ;)

Answer (score 7):

No downvote from me; +1 since it's well thought out, and I think we need some new badges to freshen things up.

The problem is, whether an answer is accepted often depends less on whether it was solid and answered the question, but whether the OP chooses to accept *any* answer, which many do not.

Moreover, we already have four badges that relate to accpeted answers in one way or another: [enlightened](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened), [guru](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/18/guru), [tenacious](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/225/tenacious), and [unsung hero](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero).

Comment: I agree on the fact that many users do not accept answers, which is again why I think a percentage may be the lesser of the two options. Maybe something just like "500 accepted answers" would be better. We do have four badges _related_ to accepted answers but none that are directly tied to it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Conner hmm so 500 * 15 = 7500 points. Isn't that enough?

Comment: As you can see by my rep, I stand nothing to gain from proposing this. I'm not making this suggestion based on greed. There are other badges that are rewarded on the same logic ("Good Answer" etc.).

Comment: Agree, let's get rid of the legendary badge too -- 30,000 points should be enough in that situation